# cast double precision as currency in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am having trouble casting a double precision value to money.

```
SELECT scrap_cost.year AS year
, scrap_cost.weekly AS week
, scrap_cost.scrap_cost::MONEY
, labor_cost.labor_cost::MONEY
FROM ...
```

returns

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type double precision to money
LINE 4: ..., scrap_cost.scrap_cost::MONEY, labor_cost.labor_cost::money
                                                            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot cast type double precision to money
SQL state: 42846
Character: 117
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `money` is a pretty useless data type.

Comment: I am writing the query in PG admin. It returns nicely in SSRS

Comment: You should be storing that as `numeric` in the first place. `double` is only an **approximate** data type. If you want to be able to retrieve the value you stored, you should stay away from double. `money` has no advantage over `numeric` but a lot of quirks and disadvantages.

Comment: Money displays with a dollar sign at the beginning though. Which was my desired result.

Comment: Unless you don't use dollar as your currency (on my system it's displayed with a € sign) https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I did to solve this was CAST it as a `numeric` first

```
SELECT 
    scrap_cost.year AS year
    , scrap_cost.weekly AS week
    , scrap_cost.scrap_cost::MONEY 
    , labor_cost.labor_cost::NUMERIC::MONEY
FROM ...
```

I found the solution in the postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html)